# How to sort list of map values by another list of map values and order them

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8

I have a list of map with the following

```
[{address=North Wilshire, name=Joe, age=16},
 {address=South Wilshire, name=Zealot, age=12},
 {address=South Wilshire, name=Astrid, age=23},
 {address=North Wilshire, name=Aaron, age=23}], 
 {address=South Wilshire, name=Aaron, age=21}]
```

and I want to sort this with another list of maps as follows

```
[{column=name, direction=ASC}, {column=age, direction=ASC}]
```

I want to be able to sort the list firstly by name, and then by age (if two of the names are the same, it will be sorted by value) so the final will look like the following:

```
[{address=South Wilshire, name=Aaron, age=21}, {address=North Wilshire, name=Aaron, age=23}, {address=South Wilshire, name=Astrid, age=23}, {address=North Wilshire, name=Joe, age=16}, {address=South Wilshire, name=Zealot, age=12}]
```

the map with the columns will be dynamic so maybe it will require sorting on all fields and sometimes maybe on one field

I've tried to somehow use Collections.sort along with Comparator.comparing to get the results but couldn't get it working for multiple columns:

```
Collections.sort(listOfMapsToSort, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.get(otherListOfMap.get(0).get("column"))));
```

I tried to loop the otherListOfMap but couldn't get it right

Comment: Is there a good reason you create a list of maps rather than a list containing a class with the corresponding fields?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
 List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps =new ArrayList<>(List.of(
         Map.of("address", "North Wilshire", "name", "Joe", "age", "16"),
         Map.of("address", "South Wilshire", "name", "Zealot", "age",
                 "12"),
         Map.of("address", "South Wilshire", "name", "Astrid", "age",
                 "23"),
         Map.of("address", "North Wilshire", "name", "Aaron", "age",
                 "23"),
         Map.of("address", "South Wilshire", "name", "Aaron", "age",
                 "21")));

// the other map that specifies the columns
List<Map<String, String>> sortCriteria = List
        .of(Map.of("Column", "name"), Map.of("Column", "age"));

// the comparator for that specification
Comparator<Map<String, String>> comp = Comparator
        .comparing((Map<String, String> map) -> map
                .get(sortCriteria.get(0).get("Column")))
        .thenComparing((Map<String, String> map) -> map
                .get(sortCriteria.get(1).get("Column")));

listOfMaps.sort(comp); // change comp to sort differently.

listOfMaps.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
{name=Aaron, address=South Wilshire, age=21}
{name=Aaron, address=North Wilshire, age=23}
{name=Astrid, address=South Wilshire, age=23}
{name=Joe, address=North Wilshire, age=16}
{name=Zealot, address=South Wilshire, age=12}
```

However, a much better way is to create a class or record to hold the values and use getters to get the values.  You can also mix types in a class where you can't in a map.  So the age could be an int.

Comment: Thanks, for that. But the code should be dynamic in terms of what will be sorted when. So in your case it's name and age but that needs to be dynamic so next time it could be just age or just name.

Comment: To do that you simply change the comparator.  You can either make a method to pass the comparator or just use it explicitly.  Also, you gave some expected output which this shows.

Comment: I modified my answer to extract the column from the `sortCriteria.`